# How to split a file into multiple files in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to split a file into multiple smaller files. The problem is if the size (which the user gives) is greater than the buffer, the program crashes otherwise it works fine. Can anyone help? Here is the code:

```
char * buffer = (char *)malloc(400);
FILE *exsistingFile = fopen(filename,"rb"); 

do
{   

    /*reading from a file */    
    bytesRead = fread( buffer, sizeof( char ), size, exsistingFile );

    /*exits if its 0 */ 
    if (bytesRead == 0)
    {
        printf("The reading has finished or the file has no data inside\n");
        return 0;
    } 

    fileCount ++;
    sprintf (newFileName,"%s%04i",output,fileCount);


    /* opening the new file bye the name given by the user */   
    outputFile = fopen(newFileName,"w");



    /*checking whether the file is opened or not*/
     if ( !outputFile )
    {
        printf( "File %s cannot be opened for reading\n", filename );
        return E_BAD_DESTINATION; 
    }

    /*write to file from the buffer*/
    fwrite(buffer,sizeof(char),bytesRead,outputFile);

    /*closing the output file*/
    fclose(outputFile);


    } while ( bytesRead > 0 );
```

Comment: At least for textual files, I would loop on reading line by line (e.g. using [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) ...). BTW Linux and Posix have [split(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html) and [csplit(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/csplit.1.html) commands. You could use them, or study their source code, since it is free software.

Comment: Your open for write fails so you output a message that the input file could not be read????

Comment: a simple fix, malloc buffer using size rather than the fixed value 400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, malloc a buffer that's as large as the size that the user gives? Or only read and write in bits of 400 bytes until you reach the size that the user gave.

```
char * buffer = (char *)malloc(400);
FILE *exsistingFile = fopen(filename,"rb"); 

do
{   
    fileCount ++;
    sprintf (newFileName,"%s%04i",output,fileCount);

    /* opening the new file bye the name given by the user */   
    outputFile = fopen(newFileName,"w");

    /*checking whether the file is opened or not*/
    if ( !outputFile )
    {
        printf( "File %s cannot be opened for writing\n", filename );
        return E_BAD_DESTINATION; 
    }

    int workSize = size;
    while (workSize)
    {
        int chunkSize = workSize > 400 ? 400 : workSize;

        /*reading from a file */    
        bytesRead = fread( buffer, sizeof( char ), chunkSize, exsistingFile );
        workSize -= bytesRead;

        /*exits if its 0 */ 
        if (bytesRead == 0)
        {
            printf("The reading has finished or the file has no data inside\n");
            return 0;
        } 

        /*write to file from the buffer*/
        fwrite(buffer,sizeof(char),bytesRead,outputFile);
    }

    /*closing the output file*/
    fclose(outputFile);

} while ( bytesRead > 0 );
```

Something like that. Except maybe a few bugs, but you get the idea. Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Yes I want read and write only bits of 400 , but the problem is that if the file is split into more 2 files . For example if the buffer is 400 , file size 1000 and user wants chunk of split file 450 . So 3 files should be created . In that case what do you do .

Comment: Make two loops. The outer loop takes care of creating output files, and the inner loop takes care of reading data in the amount the user specified.

Comment: that's what is kinds bothering me , if you could try and modify the program it would be helpful as I have tried but failed badly with 2 loops also .

Comment: Cool got it , now what id my chunk size is less than my buffer size . But I got how you did it its cool .

Comment: That's handled by 'int chunkSize = workSize > 400 ? 400 : workSize;'... If your chunk or the remaining part of a chunk is less than the buffer size, it only reads part.

Comment: yeah , tried it but its just writing the first part of the buffer nothing else , in both cases if the buffer is more or less than the chunk size .

Comment: thanks your logic is perfect . Will just have to tweak the program a little here and there . +1

Comment: In that case, please accept my reply as the accepted answer or up vote it.

Comment: will do small problem , say we have a buffer 200 chunk is 500 so its reading 200+200+200 and not 100 . how do you vote for an answer .

Comment: No it's not. If buffer is 200:
- worksize = 500. Read 200 bytes, decrease worksize by 200, so
- worksize = 300. Read 200 bytes, decrease worksize by 200, so
- worksize = 100. Read 100 bytes, because it's smaller than buffer size. Read up on the workings of the '?' in C

Comment: hi , yeah the program is working perfectly but the problem here is if the chunk size and the file size is exactly divisible then it is creating a nul file .

Answer (score 1):

```
size_t currentSize = (size >= 400) ? 400 : size;
size -= currentSize;
```

And then fread only currentSize

Comment: yeah , but then there will another loop write cause if there are more than 2 files . For example if the buffer is 400 , file size 1000 and user wants chunk of split file 450 . So 3 files should be created . In that case what do you do .

Comment: What do you mean? I can´t see the problem.

Comment: Let us say the file to split is 2000 bytes . user has given size 500 and buffer is 400 . now we set the size to 400 ,then it will open a file write it close it and it will write the rest 100 to another file . I want it to write the whole 500 to one file .

Answer (score 0):

If the `size` is a user input, you should allocate buffer in accordance to given input and not with a hard-coded value.

Comment: If the user gives a very large number my program will crash as the os wont allocate such a huge memory .

Comment: @JahirShah: No, you should test the result of `malloc` and then `{perror("malloc");exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}` on failure.

Comment: yeah actually I have to take buffer as 4096 . cant change that . and if user inputs 6000 I cant crash the program on him .